# How can I use multiple 'Data' instance when one of them is 'deduced' from a type function?

Tags: json, haskell, serialization

I'm trying to make the following code work (well, compiling first!):

```
module Orexio.Radix where

import Data.Data
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Typeable
import Text.JSON.Generic

class Resource a where
  type Representation a :: *
  identifier :: Resource a => Identifier a

class Endpoint a where
  call :: Resource a => a -> Representation a

data Identifier a = Identifier [String] deriving (Show)

data Binding a = Binding (JSValue -> Either String JSValue)

bind :: (Data a, Resource a, Endpoint a, Data (Representation a)) => Binding a
bind = Binding (\x -> binding $ query x)
  where binding query = fmap (\x -> toJSON $ call x) (resultToEither query)
        query jsvalue = fromJSON jsvalue

{-- DEMO --}

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld { 
  name :: String
} deriving (Show, Typeable, Data)

instance Resource HelloWorld where
  type Representation HelloWorld = String
  identifier = Identifier ["helloworld"]

instance Endpoint HelloWorld where
  call r = "Hello " ++ name r
```

So I had to enable `FlexibleContexts` to be able to do `Data (Representation a)`, but still it's not working...

I have this error:

```
src/Orexio/Radix.hs:21:33:
    Could not deduce (Data a0) arising from a use of `query'
    from the context (Data a,
                      Resource a,
                      Endpoint a,
                      Data (Representation a))
      bound by the type signature for
                 bind :: (Data a, Resource a, Endpoint a,
                          Data (Representation a)) =>
                         Binding a
      at src/Orexio/Radix.hs:20:9-78
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Data HelloWorld -- Defined at src/Orexio/Radix.hs:29:29
      instance Data () -- Defined in `Data.Data'
      instance (Data a, Data b) => Data (a, b) -- Defined in `Data.Data'
      ...plus 42 others
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `query x'
    In the expression: binding $ query x
    In the first argument of `Binding', namely
      `(\ x -> binding $ query x)'
```

Honestly I'm kinda of lost here, I must be missing something but what?

Here is the other extensions I have activated: `DeriveDataTypeable`, `ExistentialQuantification`, `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, `TypeFamilies`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow the advice GHC gives you: "Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)"

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher I tried to put them on different positions (on query RHS, and in binding RHS) without success. Where would you put them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `Binding a` is supposed to be a function that transforms a value of type `a` to a value of type `Representation a` or an error message.  Since the input and output are JSON-encoded, however, they both have type `JSValue`; their types don't mention `a` at all!

```
data Binding a = Binding (JSValue -> Either String JSValue)
```

There's no information to indicate what type those `JSValue`s represent.

In the definition of `bind`, the compiler knows that the return type is `Binding a`, but there's no link between that type and the types of `JSValue`s.  In particular, the compiler cannot deduce that `fromJSON` should return an `a` and that `toJSON` should take a `Representation a`.  To fix it, add explicit type signatures to `binding` and `query`.

One detail that sometimes confuses people is how to tell GHC about type variable scopes.  This needs the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.  Add `forall a.` to the type signature of `bind`, and add `forall.` to the other type signatures in the body of `bind` so that the variable `a` is properly scoped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I now understand better the issue, but I'm still struggling after adding type annotation, here is what I have now: http://lpaste.net/93263 but it still not compiling :-(

Comment: @Alois, remove the foralls and constraints from binding and query. With the foralls you are creating new type variables, but the whole point is to use the `a` from the `bind` signature.

Comment: @AloisCochard, also, did you turn on ScopedTypeVariables?

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher awesome got it working, I should read more about how scope work! thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

The essence of the type error is this line: "The type variable `a0' is ambiguous".

(Disclaimer: I'm trying to avoid jargon in this answer.)

To understand what's going on here, I suggest floating the `binding` and `query` bindings to the top-level. They successfully typecheck if you then comment out the `bind` binding. GHC infers the following types.

```
*Orexio.Radix> :i query
query :: Data a => JSValue -> Result a
*Orexio.Radix> :i binding
binding ::
  (Data (Representation a), Endpoint a, Resource a) =>
  Result a -> Either String JSValue
```

Your error is essentially caused by the expression `\x -> binding (query x)` in the definition of `bind`. Notice that the type variable `a` appears only in the domain of `binding` and the range of `query`. Thus, when you compose them, two things happen.

1. The type variable *is not* determined; its "value" remains unknown.
2. The type variable is not reachable from the type of the
   composition. For our informal purposes, that type is `JSValue -> Either
   String JSValue`.

GHC raises the error because the type variable was not determined during the composition (ie 1) *and* it can never be determined in the future (a consequence of 2).

The general shape of this problem in Haskell is more commonly known as the "`show`-`read` problem"; search for "ambiguous" on [Chapter 6](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) of Real World Haskell. (Some might also call it "too much polymorphism".)

As you and Sjoerd have determined (and the RWH chapter explains), you can fix this type error by ascribing a type to the result of `query` before applying `binding`. Without knowing your semantics, I assume that you intend this "hidden" type variable `a` to be the same as the argument to the `Binding` type constructor. So the following would work.

```
bind :: forall b.
 (Data b, Resource b, Endpoint b, Data (Representation b)) => Binding b
bind = Binding (\x -> binding $ (query x :: Result b))
```

This ascription eliminates the type variable `a` by replacing it entirely with `Result b`. Note that unlike `a` it is acceptable for `b` to remain undetermined, since it's reachable in the top-level type; uses of `bind` may each determine `b`.

That first solution requires giving `bind` an explicit signature — which can sometimes be quite onerous. In this case, due to the monomorphism restriction, you probably already need that type signature. However, if `bind` took an argument (but still exhibited this ambiguous type variable error), you could still rely on type inference by using a solution like the following.

```
dummy_ResultType :: Binding a -> Result a
dummy_ResultType = error "dummy_ResultType"

bind () = result where
  result = Binding (\x -> binding $ (query x `asTypeOf` dummy))
  dummy = dummy_ResultType result
```

(If the use of `error` worries you, cf the [Proxy type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged).)

Or trade some idiomaticness for directness:

```
withArgTypeOf :: f x -> g x -> f x
withArgTypeOf x _ = x

bind () = result where
  result = Binding (\x -> binding (query x `withArgTypeOf` result))
```

Now inference works.

```
*Orexio.Radix> :i bind
bind ::
  (Data (Representation a), Data a, Endpoint a, Resource a) =>
  () -> Binding a
```

Rest assured that GHC quickly determines after typechecking that the definition is not actually recursive.

HTH.